# find differences between lists of objects

Tags: java

In Java 11+, is there an elegant way to find the differences between 2 lists of objects?
Filtering should be done on one 'value' property of a simple col1, value object. Normally the object will contain at least 2 other properties.

Suppose I have these 2 lists:

- List 1:  ( { "left","one" }, { "left","two" } )
- List 2:  ( { "right","two" }, { "right","three" } )

The result should be a list with:

- ( { "left","one" }, { "right","three" } )

Of course there is a simplistic old way of doing this. That simple program gives:

> ColValueObject{base='left', value='Value one'}
> ColValueObject{base='right', value='Value four'}

```
public class CompareListOfObjects {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ColValueObject> list1 = List.of(
            new ColValueObject("left", "Value one"),
            new ColValueObject("left", "Value two"),
            new ColValueObject("left", "Value three"));
    List<ColValueObject> list2 = List.of(
            new ColValueObject("right", "Value two"),
            new ColValueObject("right", "Value three"),
            new ColValueObject("right", "Value four"));

    List<ColValueObject> result = findDifferencesBetweenLists(list1, list2);
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  private static List<ColValueObject> findDifferencesBetweenLists(List<ColValueObject> list1, List<ColValueObject> list2) {
    List<ColValueObject> result = new ArrayList<>();
    findUniqueEntriesInList((List<ColValueObject>) list1, (List<ColValueObject>) list2, (List<ColValueObject>) result);
    findUniqueEntriesInList((List<ColValueObject>) list2, (List<ColValueObject>) list1, (List<ColValueObject>) result);
    return result;
  }

  private static void findUniqueEntriesInList(List<ColValueObject> list1, List<ColValueObject> list2, List<ColValueObject> result) {
    for (ColValueObject l1 : list1) {
      boolean found = false;
      for (ColValueObject l2 : list2) {
        if (l1.getValue().equals(l2.getValue())) {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!found) {
        result.add(l1);
      }
    }
  }
}

class ColValueObject {
  private String base;
  private String value;

  public ColValueObject(String base, String value) {
    this.base = base;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getBase() {
    return base;
  }

  public void setBase(String base) {
    this.base = base;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "ColValueObject{" +
            "base='" + base + '\'' +
            ", value='" + value + '\'' +
            '}';
  }
}
```

Comment: Please describe exactly how the "differences" result is determined and what is "wrong" about your code.

Comment: * Differences: see the example. 
* Wrong with my code: it looks very old fashioned. AND to learn more about streaming, lambda, etc from the more experienced ones!

Comment: Your single example can be arrived at using several algorithms. Either describe in English, or show sufficient examples that cover all edge cases.

Comment: Please refer to the very nice answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is pretty simple algorithm. All you need is group all objects by the value (i.e. create a `Map`) and retreive only these objects, that are single for the given key.

```java
public static List<ColValueObject> getUnique(List<ColValueObject> one,
                                             List<ColValueObject> two) {
    // group by value
    Map<String, List<ColValueObject>> map =
            Stream.of(one, two)
                  .flatMap(List::stream)
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ColValueObject::getValue));
    
    // retreive unique lements only
    return map.values().stream()
              .filter(objs -> objs.size() == 1)
              .map(objs -> objs.get(0))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `equals` method of your `ColValueObject` type so you can match these objects only by `value`.

And then I recommend using the `removeAll` method which is either in any collection implementing `Collection` ([Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-)) or in the [CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html) library.

Basically you would have two resulting lists:

```java
List<ColValueObject> result1 = CollectionUtils.removeAll(list2, list1);
List<ColValueObject> result2 = CollectionUtils.removeAll(list1, list2);
```

Finally you can use the `addAll` method to get the final result list.

Comment: This solution was as good as the oleg.cherednik solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can first group your list by the rate of each object and count the number of occurences and second filter the resulting stream if the occurences equals 1. Afterwards you have to map the first object of EntrySet to ColValueObject and collect the final list.

```
List<ColValueObject> result = Stream.of(list1, 
list2).flatMap(List::stream).collect(groupingBy(d -> d.getValue())).entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().size() == 1).map(e -> e.getValue().get(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
```

To use this, the following static import ist necessary:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
```